# Get setter method

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a get set method in Java to get an output value from one class, into a another class. Class one prints the result as `0.0`.

This is class one.

```
Paper paperone = new Paper();
    float a = paperone.getPercentage(); 
    System.out.println("percentage " + a);
```

This is in the second class:

```
private float percentage;
    public float getPercentage() {
        return percentage; }
    public void setPercentage(float percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage; }
```

This is where I want to get the result from:

```
int total;
total = count+count1+count2;
System.out.println("The total is : ");

setPercentage((total * 100/ 5000));
System.out.println("The percentage for: " + getPercentage() + "%");
```

I am getting the count number from a list of lines being read. When I print from the second class, I get the correct result, but not from the first class. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you created new object here

```
Paper paperone = new Paper();
```

you would need to call`setPercentage` for this object as well.

If you want `percentage` field to be same for every object of `Paper` class then change its declaration to be static

```
private static float percentage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Paper paperone = new Paper();
float a = paperone.getPercentage(); 
System.out.println("percentage " + a);
```

You create a new object of `Paper` class. Its `float percentage` field is initialized to `0.0f`. You don't call `setPercentage()` so `percentage` remains `0.0f`.

By the way, use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: I changed the float to double, and it works when I used `private static float` as Robin Chander said.

Answer (score 0):

Your `total` variable is an `int`, so this line is performing integer math:

```
setPercentage((total * 100/ 5000));
```

Any value of `total` less than 50, when multiplied by 100 will be less than 5000, and the result of integer division by 5000 will be 0.

Cast it as a float to obtain the correct result:

```
setPercentage(((float) total * 100/ 5000));
```

Comment: But I am getting the correct answer in the second class where the code is being run without the get set method.